Sending multiple emits from socket.io performance vs one emit with merged object
Is sending multiple emits from socket.io to the client faster/better than sending all in one emit with a merged object?
I have an auto-emit every second to the clients.The object has many children.
Is it better to send each child separately to the client or does it work like an HTTP request and it's better to keep emitting less and merge all data to one object and one emit?
